# what is happening inside this factorial program?

Tags: c++, c, factorial

i was just playing with the factorial question using recursion when i wrote the following code.

i know that i could directly return the factorial.however i created a variable result and wrote the code below.
now what i want to know is that haven't i created n (the no. i want to calculate the factorial of)no. of result variables in the process?? because whenever my function factorial is called ,result variable is created , and each of those result variables would hold some value.

```
long long factorial(long long param) { 
    long long result;
    if (param == 1)  return 1;
    else {
        result = param * factorial(param - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

i know this is not a good code and i didn't thought that this would give me the write answer .however to my surprise it is.i want to know what is going on in this program.

Comment: each factorial has it's own result.

Comment: The code is fine.  I find that it clearly describes itself.  For those of us comfortable with recursion, this can be (and usually is) more readable than most alternatives.  Also, there are many recursive data structures for which the associated recursive code approach will describe the algorithm in use far better than the alternatives.  The factorial of 0 and 1 are both 1, by definition, which I usually handle 'outside and before' the recursion.

Comment: The code is fine, no idea why you assume it's bad code. You should congratulate yourself on discovering *recursion*.

Comment: My advice is step through the code 1 line at a time with a debugger. I recommend Visual Studio. Set a breakpoint in main before you call factorial using the F9 key. After it breaks use F10 to step into the factorial function 1 line at a time. When it steps look at flow and the values in the local and autos window.

Comment: After you stepped a few times look at the Stack Frame in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a recursive function. You can read about recursion, and about recursive debugging here:

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/recursion

https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/

Answer (score 0):

First of all : your function is unable to determine 0!

Second, yes, without any optimization from the compiler your program will take up unnecessary resources. The function is called n times and so the stack grows n times. Within each stack frame a temporary result is pushed on the stack.

However, with this program being so small, it is very likely that a minimal compiler effort will optimize that away in a release build.

It is also possible to do a recursion without the stack growing : define your factorial in such a way that there are never temporary values involved. If f(n, a) := n == 0 ? a : f(n-1, n*a) then factorial(n) := f(n, 1)
This recursion just keeps an accumulated result, wich is a fine example of functional programming. The stack needn't grow.